# preg_replace: converting line breaks into paragraphs

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert line breaks into paragraphs.

For instance

```
$string = "1st paragraph

2nd paragraph


3rd paragraph 
";
```

I want to get,

```
<p>1st paragraph</p>
<p>2nd paragraph</p>
<p>3rd paragraph</p>
```

and,

```
$string = "1st paragraph

2nd paragraph
a line break

3rd paragraph 
";
```

into,

```
<p>1st paragraph</p>
<p>2nd paragraph<br/>a line break</p>
<p>3rd paragraph</p>
```

Is it possible with `regex` and `reg_replace`? or something else better - `xpath`?

I have tried this, but no result yet,

```
echo preg_replace("'/^(.*?)(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/'", "<p>$1</p>", nl2br($string));
```

Comment: Too many delimiters. Double quotes delimit the string. Single quotes delimit the regex. A forward slash can not be followed by the start-of-string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it the other way round: First replace multiple linebreaks by paragraphs, then replace the single linebreaks by `<br>` elements.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\n(\s*\n)+/', '</p><p>', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\n/', '<br>', $str);
$str = '<p>'.$str.'</p>';
```

You also should normalize the line endings first (windows style to unix style):

```
function normalize($str) {
    // Normalize line endings
    // Convert all line-endings to UNIX format
    $s = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $str);
    $s = str_replace("\r", "\n", $s);
    // Don't allow out-of-control blank lines
    $s = preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n\n", $s);
    return $s;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I get this in the result though `<p>1st paragraph
<br>
<br>2nd paragraph
<br>
<br>3rd paragraph 
<br></p>`

Comment: @lauthiamkok perhaps you want to treat lines that contain only whitespace as empty? `/\n(\s*\n)+/`

Comment: thanks Jan - `/\n(\s*\n)+/` gives the result I want. thank you!

Comment: I noticed another problem: CRs in the input. The normalize() function I posted does the job.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "</p><p>", trim($string));
$string = preg_replace('/\n/', '<br>',$string);
$string = "<p>{$string}</p>";
```